# How many different partitions of the array are possible?

Tags: arrays

You are given an array  of size 'n'  and two integers 'l' and 'r'. You have to find the number of partitions of array such that the sum of elements in each partition lies between 'l' and 'r' (both inclusive).

```
Input: 

n = 5, l = 3, r = 12

a: [3, 5, 1, 2, 6]

Output: 

8
```

Those different partitions are as follows : -

1){3512}, {6}

2){351}, {26}

3){35} , {126}

4){35}, {12} ,{6}

5){3} , {512} , {6}

6){3}, {51}, {26}

7){3}, {5}, {126}

8){3}, {5}, {12} ,{6}

Comment: Any attempt that you did...?

Comment: What is partition of array? Is it a subset of consecutive elements or any subset of elements of array?

Comment: From the [help/on-topic]: *Questions asking for homework help **must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it**.*

Answer (score 0):

from what I understood

so you need to group the array elements but not with itself and I assume that is a problem solving question show I will answer in algorithm which is from o(n^2)

you just need to check that condition if the l,r are exclusive

```
   if n[x] + n[y] > min && n[x] + n[y] < max:
```

you just need to check that condition if the l, r are inclusive:

```
   if n[x] + n[y] => min && n[x] + n[y] <= max:
```

has array length = n, min = l, max = r

```
 partition = 0
   for x = 0 to n.length - 1:
     for y = 1 to n.length - 1: 
       if n[x] + n[y] > min && n[x] + n[y] < max:
         partition++;   
       else:
         break;
```

Here I made JS representation

```js
let n = [3, 5, 1, 2, 6]
let minN = 3, maxN = 12

let n1 = [1, 1]
let minN1 = 1, maxN1 = 2
       
console.log(getPartitions(n, minN, maxN))
console.log(getPartitions(n1, minN1, maxN1))
          
function getPartitions(n, minN, maxN) {
    let  partitions = 0;
    if (n.length > 2) {
        for (let i = 0; i < n.length - 1; i++) {
            for (let j = 1; j < n.length - 1; j++) {
                if (n[i] + n[j] > minN && n[i] + n[j] < maxN) {
                    partitions++;       
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (n.length == 2) {
        if (n[0] + n[1] >= minN && n[0] + n[1] <= maxN) {
            partitions = 1;
        }            
    }

    return partitions;
}
```

Comment: Your algorithm doesn't seem to be correct. Can you check what haappens if the input array is `[1,1]` and `min = 1` and `max = 2`?

Comment: I'm afraid it's still not working. Long story short, the maximum possible answer is `O(2^N)`. You cannot possibly achieve it incrementing a variable by 1 in two nested loops of size `O(N)`.

Comment: You are doing it completely wrong , please remove the answer.You did not get the question :-)

Comment: @Firexsecred perhaps showing your own attempt could slightly increase the chances of other participants getting the question.

Comment: @Firexsecred Considering that you wrote literally two lines as your description of the problem and showed no effort whatsoever or any attempt in solving the problem yourself, I'd say that you're the one that should change the question.

Comment: you both may want to check the question again  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the prefix sum, and then do double loop to check every partition (i,j)

Here's a code:

```
psum[0] = 0
res = 0
for i in 1..n 
    psum[i] = psum[i-1] + a[i]
for i in 1..n
    for j in i..n
        if(psum[j] - psum[i-1] <= r && psum[j] - psum[i-1] >= l)
            res++;
print(res)
```

Here's a Java code

```
int n = 5, l = 3, r = 12, ans = 0;
int a[] = {3, 5, 1, 2, 6};
int psum[] = new int[n+1];
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) psum[i] = psum[i-1] + a[i-1];
for(int i=1; i <= n; i++)
  for(int j=i; j <= n; j++)
     if(psum[j] - psum[i-1] <= r && psum[j] - psum[i-1] >= l)
        ans++;
System.out.println(ans);
```

Comment: your code gave wrong output :( It gives '11' as the answer :(((

Comment: @Firexsecred I think there is more than 8, you can do System.out.println(i + " " + j); instead of ans++; and see all partitions.

Answer (score 0):

c++ code of partition a array

```
 //int n=5, l = 3, r = 12;
//int arr[5] = {3, 5, 1, 2, 6};
complete traverse this using given algo
it will be very help to understand an code given below 

ll a[n];

memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
        if (arr[n-1]<=r&&arr[n-1]>=l) a[n-1]=1;

      for (ll i=n-2;i>=0;i--){
            ll sum=0;
            for (ll j=i;j<n;j++){
                sum+=arr[j];
                if (sum<=r&&sum>=l){
                    if (j==n-1){
                        a[i]=a[i]%1000000007+1;
                    }
                    else a[i]=(a[i]%1000000007+a[j+1]%1000000007)%1000000007;
                }
            }
        }
print(a[0])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
static int getPartitions(int[] arr, int minN, int maxN) {
        int n=arr.length;
        int[] ans=new int[n];

        int[]  parSum=new int[n];
        parSum[0]=arr[0];
        for (int i=1;i<n;i++){
            parSum[i]=parSum[i-1]+arr[i];
        }

        if (arr[n-1]<=maxN&&arr[n-1]>=minN) ans[n-1]=1;

        for (int i=n-2;i>=0;i--){
            int sum=0;
            for (int j=i;j<n;j++){
                sum+=arr[j];
                if (sum<=maxN&&sum>=minN){
                    if (j==n-1){
                        ans[i]+=1;
                    }
                    else ans[i]+=ans[j+1];
                }
            }
        }
        return ans[0];
    }
```

This will work for sure.

Comment: can you give me case where it fails?I think it should work.